# How to import JavaScript libraries with ViteJS in HTML?

Tags: javascript, npm, href, vite

I am using ViteJS to `npm install` any libraries or packages that I need, and I plan to use vanilla JavaScript and HTML.  One of the libraries I am using is called [os-gui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-gui), a styling library.  The docs state that I can use npm install it, but also calls for directly importing the library in the HTML like this:

[image]

Since I am not using ReactJS but ordinary HTML, and since I have not directly downloaded the library, how can I properly format the `href` so that it points to the correct packages that I downloaded in `npm`?

Comment: `<script type="module">import jquery from 'jquery.js'</script>`

Comment: But that doesn’t answer how to import the os-gui packages themselves.

Comment: you need to use a cdn like unpkg.com